# With XSLT/XPath, how can I match any element in the null namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
```

matches the foo element in the null namespace.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

matches any element in *any* namespace.

I tried:

```
xmlns:null=""
...
<xsl:template match="null:*">
```

but it's illegal to declare a prefix for the null namespace.

So how can I match an element with any name in the null namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
<xsl:template match='*[namespace-uri() = ""]'>
```

If the node-set is empty or has no namespace URI, an empty string is returned by the `namespace-uri` function, which should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

ffpf is correct.

For even more clarity I would recommend to use the following match pattern:

'**`*[not(namespace-uri() )]`**'